# How to create a post type 'supports' in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i need a costum label in wordpress plugin post page

```
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Filtrar categorias por gênero',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor','custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'Eventos' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );
```

In case I need to add a form, But I do not know where to create this form, can only demonstrate it "supports"